# reading a file in js is corupting the file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf

in js i'm running this code

```
let str = new TextDecoder("utf8").decode(new Uint8Array(reader.result));

let data = {
    name:file.name,
    size: args.loaded,
    contentsize:str.length,
    type:file.type,
    content:str
};
let res = await $.post({
    url:"/api/files",
    data:JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
})
```

reader.result is the output of

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

which is then being picked up in php

```
$new["actual"] =strlen($new["content"]);
$new["content"] = new MongoDB\BSON\Binary($new["content"] ,MongoDB\BSON\Binary::TYPE_GENERIC);
$result = IO::$db->files->insertOne($new);
```

which then results in a db document of

```
{ 
    "name" : "test.pdf", 
    "size" : NumberInt(128454), 
    "contentsize" : NumberInt(122693), 
    "type" : "application/pdf", 
    "actual" : NumberInt(215693)
}
```

however when i remove the content of the file back to the file system the file is corrupted and wont open.
i've run the file comparer that comes with VSCode over it and says there are 0 differences between the DB content and the original, so i can only think the issues is with the 3kb difference in the file size and the read content, but what or why escapes me

note only seems to be Binary files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the UTF-8 specification does not include characters for all bit codes in the byte data range, other languages such as PHP get around this by adding special non-UTF-8 characters that complete the byte code mapping, but this is not the case in JavaScript

So this is a limitation of JavaScript and that instead of telling you that it has hit a byte code it can't de-serialise which would highlight that an issue has occurred it just skips that byte an moves on to the next, corrupting your data and hiding why that corruption occurred.

this means that you can't use the UTF-8 encoder in JavaScript to encode anything includes one of the none supported byte codes, to get around this one option would be to convert the byte to is HEX string and then use that to de-serialise on the server side, this causes a degree of data bloating as you are using 2 bytes to send one byte (though this is much less than trying to encode an array of bytes) but as a 2 letter hex string maps all byte range values means there is no corruption of the binary data and can be safely used in a text based data serialisation like JSON via JavaScript

Comment: You make this sound like it was a deficit in Javascript. The actual error is in pretending some arbitrary binary is UTF-8 encoded text and applying an UTF-8 decoder in the first place. (Strictly speaking, though, it shouldn't *skip bytes* it cannot interpret as UTF-8 encoded character data, it should return a *replacement character* � instead.)

Comment: i would say not reporting an error was a defect, if it had reported that it encountered an erroneous bit code that it couldn't decode I would have known there was an issue and what that issue was, however if it used the replacement characters like you suggest then it would work the same way as other languages that support binary string data like PHP and then UTF-8 decoder would work, either way it is a definite limitation of the language

Comment: Which (seriously) goes back to my answer - don't treat PDF as text because it is not. UTF-8 is a text encoding - PDF files are binary. Those two things shouldn't be mixed. You might not like that answer, but it's still true.

Comment: but you wouldn't explain what you meant you just gave a high level answer with no details and expected knowledge to appear, as i said in my reply to you i was working entirely in in binary so the answer "be more binary" is not the same as "UTF8 in js doesn't support all binary data so can't be used with binary values" one is an arbitrary statement that doesn't explain the problem the other is an explanation an answer that doesn't impart understanding is no answer

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a PDF file. PDF files are not text files and should not be handled as text files. If you change line endings, this will change the offset of the different objects in the file, which will corrupt the PDF file. Even worse, if there are binary streams in the PDF file (such as for fonts, images etc...), it will break the contents of the streams and likely make it impossible to decode them.

To solve this, make sure you read and write PDF files as binary files.

Comment: perhaps you could explain, at all

Comment: I just did. I don't write PHP, but I'm sure there is plenty of documentation on how to read and write files binary in PHP.

Comment: so i'm reading a binary stream into a byte array, instructing javascript that it can use the UTF8 encoding to interpret the byte array as a string, i'm then passing the binary data via a http to php where it receives the binary input stream and decodes it into a binary string and then saved it to the database is an binary field as it is binary data from beginning to end exactly which part need to be more binary